# Two wireless extenders with same mac address...How to assign IP address dhcp

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, mac-address

I have two wireless extenders, and they both have the exact same mac address (same make and model)

Now, they work fine in the network, I just wanted to know how can I assign them specific IP addresses if they have the same MAC?

Thanks!

Comment: Can be called a model wireless extender?

Comment: It should be possible to change the MAC address on most modern hardware.